# How to change the length and direction of footnote separator line in LaTeX?

Tags: footnotes

I want to shorten the length of the footnote separator line. And also I would like it to be drawn from right to left. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Welcome and an happy new year. Add your MWE. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redefine `\footnoterule`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} %

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\raggedleft\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}\vspace*{0.6ex}}

\begin{document} %

\lipsum[1] \footnote{Some silly foot note. Some silly foot note. Some silly foot note. Some silly foot note. Some silly foot note. Some silly foot note. Some silly foot note. }%
\lipsum[2-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]